# Compose Gmail Email using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, gmail

Using VBA in Excel, and user is already signed into Gmail, how can I compose an email in Gmail without sending, either as a draft or as a pop-up? I've seen several examples of using credentials to send email, but can I do it without using credentials because the user is already logged in?

```
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "someone@gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "*******"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
    .Update
End With



With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "me@hotmail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .From = """Dave"" <me@hotmail.com>"
    .Subject = "New form"
    .AddAttachment TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
    .Send
End With
```

EDIT: My company uses Outlook but we are switching to Google soon. In my auto generated email in Outlook, in Excel I take certain cells to help populate the subject line, body, and email recipient. I am hoping to do the same process but instead of using Outlook, I would like to use Google.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "without using credentials" you mean by using a session that is already logged in on a browser? I'm confused as to what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I will edit with more background on what I want to accomplish.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Gmail RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) before you try to do this with CDO.